# matDatepickerFilter breaks mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I need to disable some months and days in `mat-datepicker` but when I am trying to set `[matDatepickerFilter]` it breaks my `mat-datepicker` totally (see below).

[image: Screenshot]

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Reporting period</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="periodDp" [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter" [(ngModel)]="filter.period">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="periodDp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #periodDp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
dateFilter = (date: Date) => date.getMonth() % 2 === 1 && date.getDate() % 2 === 0;
```

What's wrong? I have same situation with `[dateClass]` attribute, without the filter all works perfectly.

Comment: Whats the error which you are seeing in your browser console ?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the filter with a boolean value like

```
     myFilter = (date: Date): boolean => {
  return date.getMonth() % 2 === 1 && date.getDate() % 2 === 0;
  }
```

here is a working demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvtat7?file=app/datepicker-filter-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
myFilter = (d: any): boolean => {
    let fechaFormat = new Date(d);
    const day = (fechaFormat || new Date()).getDay();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6 &&;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Fabio! Answers must have an explanation on how/why the code you provide is relevant to the question.